# What is the fastest algorithm to choose the max votes in an array?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

**The Problem:**

There is an employee vote taking place to choose the next board member:

- An employee can vote for only one nominee by choosing that persons
  unique employee number (where employee number is an integer >= 0)
- The votes are stored in an array
- The person who receives the most votes will be chosen as the next
  board member

What is the most efficient algorithm for choosing a board member?

*Sub-problem*: what if we knew that the number of candidates was less than the number of voters, is there are more efficient algorithm?

**Possible Solutions?**

Would using a hash table make sense in this case, since each nominee will have a unique ID?

Or can we sort the array first (assuming the array is not sorted initally) and then keep track of the winner by iterating through the array and keeping track of the max counter:

Votes[id] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4]

So just iterate through the entire array and maxCount = 4 for voterID = 3

Thus, 3 is the winner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic space vs performance tradeoff.

Hash table takes one pass through the data (N).
Sort + count takes (N logN + N).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this was my initial feeling as well.

Comment: So if there were 5 candidates we could just use their ID's to perform hash lookups which is presumably O(1) since each person will have unique ID (so no collisions)

Comment: If the hash is "large enough" then it is O(1)

Comment: Assuming perfect hash would it be "correct" to say that it's O(1)*n nominees = O(n)